# How to make a header full screen background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, fullscreen

I want to make a header full screen with background img but I have a problem

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Super Tramp</a></h1>
                <h2 class="title">Sketch your next vacation route today</h2>
                <h3 class="sub-title">The Best Landing Page Travel Website for your vacation.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <form>
                    <p class="info">
                        Enter the required data and <br>
                        continue to choose the route.
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Full Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Email Adress">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                     </div>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">Request Vacation</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is the HTML Markup

```
header {
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
),url("../image/bg-header.jpg");
background-size: cover;
margin-bottom: 35px;

h1 {
    margin-top: 68px !important;
    text-align: center;

    a {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'montserrat-semibold';
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        padding: 11px 16px;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        &:active {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'montserrat-regular';
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    font-size: 1.56em;
}

form {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.form-group input, .form-control {
    height: 69px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #626262;
}
```

}

this is the CSS Markup

but the problem is form part of the header comes out and does not know how I can solve the problem

[http://gyazo.com/ef00bdc833ac1e1d26cd8423a132ecc2][1]

[1]: http://gyazo.com/ef00bdc833ac1e1d26cd8423a132ecc2 here it`s a image with the problem.

Comment: Can you create a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for the same?

Comment: Not completely sure how to do this type of stuff with Bootstrap but I recommend taking a look at [viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) - to make an element fill the screen just use `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`.

Comment: height: 100vh; remove this from header

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

html:- (assigned ID)

```
<header id="thisHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Super Tramp</a></h1>
                <h2 class="title">Sketch your next vacation route today</h2>
                <h3 class="sub-title">The Best Landing Page Travel Website for your vacation.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <form>
                    <p class="info">
                        Enter the required data and <br>
                        continue to choose the route.
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Full Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Email Adress">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                     </div>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">Request Vacation</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS (no change)

Add some jQuery:-

```
$(document).reday(function(){
var clientHeight = $( window ).height();
  $('#thisHeader').css('height', clientHeight);

});
```

Comment: I tried but it didn`t work, on large device looks good but in small devices don`t.